# c# Microsoft Graph permissions to read mails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, permissions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following list of permissions on Azure AD:

[image]

my ASP.NET Web Core app has the following config:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "ClientId": "e24xxxxxxf",
    "ClientSecret": "RDYxxxxxmL",
    "ClientCertificates": [
    ],
    "ClientCapabilities": [ "cp1" ],
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "mail.read mail.readbasic mail.readbasic.all user.read"
  },
```

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
   .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

var config = builder.Configuration;

string[]? initialScopes = config.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(config.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(config.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.UseAuthorization();



app.MapRazorPages();


app.Run();
```

When I try to open page, page requested only base profile permissions and email address:

[image]

when I call

```
var inbox = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

after approving these permissions, I get an error:

> ServiceException: Code: InvalidMsaTicket Message: ErrorCode:
> 'PP_E_RPS_REASON_OFFERACTIONS_INVALID'. Message: ''

but it works fine for calling:

```
var currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

Why mail reading is not requested and how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you referred to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core).

`Microsoft Graph permissions to read mails` means we can use Ms graph api to read mails. So we need to pass the authentication first to get the consent to access the api. What you showed in your questions are the configurations to integrate azure ad authentication into your .net 6 web application, which will provide UI to let users sign in so that your application can call the api to get mails of the signed user. So you also need to add UI in your code.

After adding the authentication part, we also need to call the api, we can use graph SDK here. And you may check my code below/

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var config = builder.Configuration;

string[]? initialScopes = config.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(config)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(config.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

// Require authentication
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
// Enables a UI and controller for sign in and sign out.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

appsetting.json, pls follow the document to register azure ad application, create client secret and configure authentication:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "client_id",
    "Domain": "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
    "CallbackPath": "/home/index"
},
"DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
}
```

Controller, using graph SDK to query graph api:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebMvcAzure.Models;

namespace WebMvcAzure.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

        public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
        {
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        public async Task<string> mailsAsync() {
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
            var mail = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.Request().GetAsync();
            return "success";
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add a login view `_LoginPartial.cshtml` in the `Shared` folder and add the partial view into `_layout.cshtml`

```
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
}
else
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
}
</ul>
```

[image]

**Test result**:

[image]

Comment: as I said, I don't have problem with authentication, it works to call profile. It does not work to get messages because server does not ask appropriate permissions

Comment: Please, try to use graph SDK to call api to get your mails. `var mail = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.Request().GetAsync();
` the screenshot you provided in question doesn't make sense, you can see my appsettings, I only set `user.read` in the scopes, it also doesn't make sense, because in azure ad, I've add the `mail.read` permission. In your code snippet, I didn't see the code that calling graph api, so I don't know how to call that api. So I share my code for calling graph api to get messages.

Comment: I added my calling `_graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.Request().GetAsync()` to my main post and result, which I get after it.

Comment: The error messages means the token is invalid, I'm not sure about it. Per may check, firstly  you are missing `app.UseAuthentication();` but I don't think it makes sense. I updated my controller to add code about generating access token. I recommend you to generate a token and then decode it to check if the token contained correct value in `scp` claim.

Comment: When I try to call `var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadToken(accessToken);` I get an exception `ArgumentException: IDX12709: CanReadToken() returned false. JWT is not well formed: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
The token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.`

Comment: If I call `await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();` - it works fine with the same token, if I call `await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.Request().GetAsync();` I get that exception

Comment: good day sir, actually I don't know how you composed your `_graphServiceClient`, per my knowledge, when I use graph client, I didn't generate access token for it. So I don't understand `If I call await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync(); - it works fine with the same token` well.... By the way, my sample code is based on a newly created .net 6 MVC project, and I showed all the code and configurations I added in this project, could you pls create a new project and completely take a try with my code? And I think you may also try `graph explore` to test if you can get correct messages

Comment: graph explore: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/

Comment: I created code exactly as you described and got: `ServiceException: Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
ClientRequestId: af799df1-f66f-41ab-99e5-0e10f0ebcd2b`. What is your configured AD application? Probably, it depends on 'Starting November 9th, 2020 end users will no longer be able to grant consent to newly registered multitenant apps without verified publishers.  Add MPN ID to verify publisher' which I get in my AD ?

Comment: `What is your configured AD application` --- I used the azure ad client id here, the azure ad app is the app which I give the consent of `Mail.Read` api permission. This azure ad app is a multi-tenant app, but I used it in my own tenant.

Comment: `no longer be able to grant consent to newly registered multitenant apps` Actually I always used admin consent to allow api permissions, I'm not familar with `without verified publishers`. According to your description, it seems that the admin changed some policy in azure ad.

Comment: on code, we may need to check the access token(suggestions comes from [this answer](ErrorAccessDenied Message: Access is denied)), on configuration, it seems that you need to contact the admin to check if he changed any policy.