# Get user presence using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

[Update 1]
This is a unatented screen showing a webpage with people and che calendar for the day for those people.
For the calendar I use ExchangeService and that works fine with oauth and with the app registered and and tennantid and client secret.
However I would also lige to get the presence of those users in the same way using graph.

I'm trying to get user presence using graph using a client app using oauth.

I have read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

It doesn't say how the auth provider is made, but I guess it sould look like the one I have created.

What should I do?
I have tried to give the following permissions:
**Presence.ReadWrite.All**

But I get this error:

**ServiceException: Code: Forbidden**

```
public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient()
{
    ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential(MyTenantId, MytAppId, MyClientSecret);
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
    return graphClient;
}

public static async void GetPressence(string emailadr)
{   
    var client = GetGraphClient();
    var presence = client.Users[emailadr].Presence.Request().GetAsync();
    var r = presence.Result;    
}
```

Comment: Which account are you using , is this a personal microsoft or work / school account , make sure you have  delegated permission.

Comment: First thing: make the code really async: public static async Task GetPressence(string emailadr) and then var presence = await client.Users[emailadr].Presence.Request().GetAsync();

Comment: As @vickykumar mentioned. Looks like you are running daemon app but get presence endpoint doesn't support application permissions

Comment: @vickykumar It is a standallone webpage, the part where I get data from ExchangeService works, strange that graph doesnt support calls in the same way)

Answer (score 2):

You are now trying to call ms graph api to get user's presence information, we need to check the [api permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) first. We can see it only support `Delegated (work or school account)` permission.

[image]

This means you have to have a work or school account and sign in your application first, then this is the auth provider and you can use it to call graph api. By the way, `Application` permission type is not supported, so you [can't use this auth provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider).

[image]

You need to use [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider). Since you didn't mention what kind of application you have now, pls note, it you are having a `daemon app`, such as console application/web api and those don't have a web page to let users sign in with their work or school account, you are not able to use this api to implement your requirement. So let's assume you have a web application. Here's the [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-applications), you can take a look at the "call ms graph" sample. If you had an asp.net core app, you need to change the `Startup.cs` to configure the authentication basically. You also need to change the `appsettings.json` file for adding configuration. You also need to inject the graph SDK into your controller.

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

And I have an asp.net core MVC sample for calling ms graph api [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71963533/14574199).

Comment: I want to get all users presence inside of my company to be used in a tool i am currently writing. 
I can't use the presence API solong the i don't have a public facing web interface with a redirect URI?

Comment: `get all users presence` usually points to a "list xxx" API, but the presentance API doesn't have such kind of feature, we might need to use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/cloudcommunications-getpresencesbyuserid?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) instead.

Comment: ` i don't have a public facing web interface with a redirect URI` --> which means you are not able to use auth provider like the one mentioned in this answer, but the API I shared also only support `Delegated (work or school account)`, so I'm afraid you can't implement your requirement....you might create a new question in SO to ask for more help from other communitors?

Comment: Yeah i will thank you. 
It seems weird, not being able to get user presence with an application auth flow but if it isn't supported i have to use some workarounds